# Add IBAction to a button in a custom UItableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ibaction

So I want to make an order of different products. In this 
I have a custom uitableview cell with a button on it. In give a NSMutualArray with my IBAction. This is my IBAction. I allocated my arrayBestelling in my viewdidload.

```
-(IBAction)addProduct:(NSMutableArray *) arrProduct{
    [arrayBestelling addObject:arrProduct];

}
```

Ok this is my whole tableviewMethod.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    productTableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productTableviewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {   
                cell = (productTableviewCell*)view;
            }
            }
    }
    if(searching) {
        cell.proId.text = [[[copyArrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.product.text = [[[copyArrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_naam"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.prijs.text = [[[copyArrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_prijs"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

    }else {


    NSString *strId = [[[arrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *strNaam = [[[arrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_naam"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.product.text = strNaam;
    cell.proId.text = strId;
    NSMutableString *strPrijs = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"€ "];
    [strPrijs appendString:[[[arrayProducts valueForKey:@"Pro_prijs"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]];
    cell.prijs.text = strPrijs;
    NSString *strAantal = cell.aantal.text;

    arrayProBestelling = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arrayProBestelling addObject:strId];
        [arrayProBestelling addObject:strNaam];
        [arrayProBestelling addObject:strPrijs];
        [arrayProBestelling addObject:strAantal];

    }

   **[cell.btnadd addTarget:self action:@selector(addProduct:arrayProBestelling) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]**

    return cell;

}
```

Anybody can help?

EDIT !

Comment: Are you adding an Array to other Array? I dont understand, what you are asking

Comment: Your code isn't working? What's happening? Not quite sure what you're trying to do. Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I have a array Products. This array contains a product_name,product_price,product_id and product_amount. And now I want to add this arrayProduct to arrayBestelling.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a custom data class called Product with those name, price, etc as fields. Then you add the Products to the MutableArray.

```
-(IBAction)addProduct:(Product *) product{
    [productArray addObject:product];
}
```

You can then sort the array using SortDescriptors:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons to the -accessoryView for the cell. If you are building your own custom cell, this isn't hard at all. But for a plain simple implementation, just create a UIButton, assign a target, and add it to the accessoryView.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourbutton.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;
```